# Can we say "you're taking it so simply"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

We have this phrase

> **[take somebody/something seriously](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/take-somebody-something-seriously)**
>
> to believe that someone or something is worth your attention or
> respect
>
> As a teacher, it’s important that the kids take you seriously.
>
> It’s only a joke – don’t take it seriously!

Similarly, can I say "**You are taking it so simply**" or "**You are putting it so simply**" when you want to mean that person is looking at the matter superficially because he is thinking about the matter in a simple way and does not have any deep understanding of it?

Say, I posted a question on Quora asking if I can say "Our school **has** a trip to the zoo next week” or “Our school is **having** a trip to the zoo next week".

A native English speaker said “Neither one makes sense. They should be: “Our school [is][will be] **taking** a trip to the zoo next week.”

Then, I thought that person was "**taking the question so simply**" or "**putting the question so simply**" (I am not sure if that is the way to say it) because I think the verb "*has*" here means "*organize*" not "*go on a trip*". It seems that Americans prefer "*I am taking a trip*" while the British prefer "*I am going on a trip*"

Comment: "Putting it simply" usually means "explaining something in a simple way" (to help a child or a non-expert to understand it). "Taking it simply" isn't idiomatic.

Comment: It's not idiomatic to use ***simply*** as the antonym of ***seriously*** in such contexts. The adverbial sense you seek can be conveyed by, for example, *You're taking this too **casually / light-heartedly / nonchalantly / ...***

Comment: Is this question supposed to be about the use of ***simply***, or ***going on / taking** a trip*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers comment is the answer. Moreover, you misuse "superfluously" in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *You're looking at it so simply*

The phrase is not idiomatic in English. An improvement would be to replace "so" with "too" and swapping *simply* with *simplistically*

2. *You're looking at it **too simplistically***

*[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/simplistically)* defines it as

> **in a way that is simplistic (= making something complicated seem more simple than it is)**:
>
> - The issue should not be viewed simplistically.
> - Interpreting data too simplistically may obscure critical information.
> - Maybe I am looking at things too simplistically, but some of the solutions to our problems are obvious.

Alternatively, one could reply with:

3. **You're [missing the point](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/miss-the-point)**. I'm asking whether the present simple or the present continuous should be used in this situation.

We use this expression to tell someone that they have misunderstood or *overlooked* the main crux of the issue.

> ## *miss the point*
>
> to not understand something correctly or what is important about it: